# getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(col) is not supported on a range with a filtered out row

Tags: google-apps-script, filter, spreadsheet

I try to remove filters from filtered out columns, but I get this error:

```
function _filterCompetitors() {
  mailTab.getRange('G7').activate();
  var toInclude = mailTab.getRange('B5').getValue();
  if (toInclude != "") {
    _setIncludedWinners(toInclude.split(",").map(item => item.trim()));
  }
  else {
    var toExclude = mailTab.getRange('B6').getValue();
    if (toExclude != "") {
      _selectExcludedWinners(toExclude.split(",").map(item => item.trim()));
    }
  }
}

function _filterDates(){
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenDateBefore(SpreadsheetApp.RelativeDate.YESTERDAY)
  .whenDateAfter(new Date(mailTab.getRange('P9').getValue()))
  .build();  
  mailTab.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(6, criteria);
}
```

and then:

```
function _clearFilters() {
  mailTab.getRange('G7').activate();
  for (col = 1; col < 8; col++) {
    Logger.log("col "+col);
    mailTab.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(col);
  }
}
```

Error in log:

```
Exception: This operation is not supported on a range with a filtered out row.
```

I have also tried:

```
function _clearDatesFilter(){
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .build();  
  mailTab.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(6, criteria);
}
```

And got:

```
Exception: This operation is not supported on a range with a filtered out row.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested your script to the sheet which has the basic filter in the columns "A" to "H", no error occurs. I apologize for this. So, can I ask you about the detail of the method for replicating your issue?

Comment: Added the the code I had run before trying to clear the filters.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about the method for executing those functions of `_filterCompetitors`, `_filterDates` and `_clearFilters`. And also, I couldn't understand about the functions of `_setIncludedWinners` and `_selectExcludedWinners`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: At which line are you receiving the error? Moreover, have your filters been cleared successfully? Have you tried using `flush()`?